# How to get today's date in BPMN timer

Tags: timer, camunda, bpmn

So I need that timer in BPMN that will be *type: date*, but instead of putting exact date (like 2022-08-04T08:30:00) I want to get today's date and the hour that is right now. Is it possible to do it in Camunda Modeler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use expressions in the modeler that will be executed at runtime. There exist [internal context functions](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/user-guide/process-engine/expression-language/#internal-context-functions) that might be interesting for you.

Untested, but entering this as the timer value should work:

```
${dateTime().plusHours(1)}
```

If the builtin functions are not enough for you, you could just use the value of an existing process-variable (`${variableName}`) and set the variable value to any date value you like (via executionListener, service task, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

See Camunda [Internal Context Functions](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/expression-language/#internal-context-functions).
There are several functions that can be used in expressions.
To get todays Date use:

```
${now()}
```

**Note:** This function gives a Java **Date** object. These Classes have been long deprecated and the new `java.time.*` classes should be used.